# Landing to Particular form in Embedded Envelope with multiple forms

Tags: docusignapi

My requirement :
Creating DocuSign embedded envelope which contains multiple documents(doc1,doc2 and doc3) for signing by single signer. I want to be generate embedded signing url(one time url) which will land me to desired document - say on doc3 directly.

is it possible to achieve this in DocuSign?

Answer (score 1):

When a recipient first enters/opens an Envelope, they'll always see the first page of the first document initially -- there's no way to have DocuSign automatically scroll down to a subsequent document in the Envelope as soon as the Envelope is opened.

However, you can somewhat control 'auto-navigation' by using the Account-level setting "**Signing auto-navigation rule**" (located in **Preferences >> Features** page of the DocuSign web console...and described on page 27 of the Admin guide: http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/Account%20Administration%20Reference%20Guide.pdf).

[image: account setting]

If you set **Signing auto-navigation rule** to "Navigate blank required fields" as I've shown above, and the Envelope contains 3 documents, but only the third document requires input from the signer (i.e., no incomplete required tabs for the recipient are located in the first two documents), then the user experience will be as follows:

- Recipient opens Envelope and sees page 1 of doc 1, with a "Start" button shown on the left: [image]
- Recipient clicks the "Start" button and the envelope automatically scrolls/navigates down to the recipient's first required tab (located in document 3): [image]

So, using the **Signing auto-navigation rule** setting as described above may somewhat allow you to meet your requirement, depending on which Envelope documents in your scenario contain required tabs for the recipient.

Comment: thanks @Kim Brandl. We are already using autonavigation rules. But they wont come handy in this situation as all documents have mandatory signing tab. Anyways thanks for confirming that it can not be achieved.